# PHP-generated javascript and quote marks

Tags: php, javascript, quotes, quoting

I'm generating some javascript in my PHP code, and I need to assign some php variables to javascript variables. Unfortunately, sometimes my PHP variables contain quote marks. for instance:

```
$foo = "'Dis here be a \"string\"";
print "<script type='text/javascript'>var foo = '{$foo}';</script>";
```

will generate a javascript error because the resulting javascript will look like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var foo = '"'Dis here be a \"string\"';
```

I know I can use regexp on $foo to replace all `'` marks with `\'` but this is hard for various reasons. Is there anything I can do short of that? Something akin to the perl `q()` function...

Comment: What are some of these "various reasons"?

Comment: Do you have magic quotes turned on? That may be the issue.

Comment: various reasons are that this js is being generated by a smarty template and smarty doesn't let you use full php, but {$foo|addslashes} does the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried doing this?

```
$foo = "'Dis here be a \"string\"";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var foo = "'.addslashes($foo).'";</script>';
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Addslashes() is sufficient in this case, but won't escape *every* character that could potentially bork a js string.

Comment: addslashes is what i was looking for, and seems to work for now.

Comment: @Frank is right though, it won't take into account everything related to a javascript string.

Answer (score 3):

I use json_encode().

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

This should be a step in the right direction:

```
addcslashes($str, "\"\r\n\\\t/\0..\37");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure? Isn't it:

```
var foo = ''Dis here be a "string"'
```

---

In order to prevent the double ' try:

```
$foo = "\'Dis here be a \"string\"";
```

or

```
$foo = '\\\'Dis here be a "string"';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that you can use a PHP file as a JavaScript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.php"></script>
```

And you're able to execute PHP code in that file, as well as output JavaScript code by echoing from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the final value in JavaScript, I would use `json_encode`:

```
$foo = "'Dis here be a \"string\"";
print "<script type='text/javascript'>var foo = " . json_encode($foo) . ";</script>";
```

And it will correctly output:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var foo = "'Dis here be a \"string\"";</script>
```

Notice I didn't put an extra set of quotes around the `json_encode` function. It will add the necessary quotes to make it a valid JavaScript string automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Frank Farmer's answer is interesting, but it's escaping some things that don't need to be escaped, like tabs.

Try this snippet, it works just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hi!\n\tHi!\n<?php echo '\tHI!',"\\n\tHI!";?>");
</script>
```

Since I'm always connected to a database in my PHP scripts that pass text directly into Javascript strings, I lean on real_escape_string to do my dirty work. addslashes() doesn't handle newlines and those sometimes sneak into strings I'm passing on to Javascript.

A simple `$sql->real_escape_string($string)` makes it all better, escaping whatever the database spits out into a Javascript-friendly form.